# Repairing hosed Grub installation

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning

I'm trying to fix a botched install by Hewlett Packard.  They shipped the laptop with Ubuntu 14.04LTS and I wasn't smart enough to nuke and reinstall the whole thing when I first got it.

The primary problem I had was that the /boot partition and filesystem was only 200 megs and Ubuntu needs 100M for the current kernel and 100M+ for the next updated kernel so my system updates from Ubuntu stopped working.

I've burned a Knoppix 7.6 DVD to help me repartition and rearrange things to get a larger partition.  I was able to successfully move /, /home and the swap partitions (which HP pre-installed) into an LVM Volume Group.  This was a success and would successfully boot, using the new LVs for /, /home and swap.

Next I tried enlarging the existing /boot partition to 2 gigs, which worked, except Knoppix wouldn't enlarge the fat32 filesystem underneath it.  So, I nuked it (backing it up first) and recreated it as a 2G ext4 filesystem in its own partition (not part of LVM).

Now, I can't get grub to work currently.  In fact, I can boot to Knoppix, but the laptop firmware doesn't seem to see grub at all ("No Operating System Found" error mesage).  It acts like I don't have an OS installed.  However, under Knoppix, grub seems to be installed.

I'm following the instructions found here (http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd), so I mount my lvm vg1-root as /media/root, and /dev/sda1 as /media/root/boot.  Then I mount dev, dev/pts, proc, and sys under /media/root.  Lastly I chroot to /media/root.

Now when I run grub-install (as root in the chrooted window) and grub-install --recheck I get:

```
root@Microknoppix:/# grub-install /dev/sda
Installing for i386-pc platform.
Installation finished. No error reported.
root@Microknoppix:/# grub-install --recheck /dev/sda
Installing for i386-pc platform.
Installation finished. No error reported.
```

Checking the resulting /boot/grub/grub.cfg file, all the UUID references match what I'd expect from blkid.  Of course, booting doesn't seem to get that far.  For grins:

```
knoppix@Microknoppix:~$ sudo blkid
/dev/cloop0: UUID="2016-01-20-01-28-35-89" LABEL="KNOPPIX_FS" TYPE="iso9660"
/dev/cloop1: UUID="2015-12-30-05-31-30-00" LABEL="KNOPPIX_FS1" TYPE="iso9660"
/dev/zram0: UUID="d006c8b0-f899-48f1-a7d1-2327b72126f0" TYPE="swap"
/dev/sda1: LABEL="BOOT" UUID="5bd116ab-46ef-4b4e-ac70-711cd0085a55" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="64a7963a-01"
/dev/sda4: SEC_TYPE="msdos" LABEL="HP_TOOLS" UUID="7930-F46B" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="64a7963a-04"
/dev/sda5: LABEL="LINUX_OLD" UUID="d519b0f8-e1a4-443b-975c-8df2af1def4e" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="64a7963a-05"
/dev/sda6: UUID="dxe30Q-xL3c-AzwH-ZPyy-Z2rv-4z3R-Y2LY2T" TYPE="LVM2_member" PARTUUID="64a7963a-06"
/dev/sr0: UUID="2016-01-24-15-29-37-00" LABEL="KNOPPIX" TYPE="iso9660"
/dev/mapper/vg1-home: LABEL="HOME" UUID="503b3f2f-77b1-40c2-a064-c4fe34980b69" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/mapper/vg1-root: LABEL="LINUX" UUID="f55ffea3-bf95-435a-bb3f-d0123f1822d7" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/mapper/vg1-swap: LABEL="SWAP" UUID="79b246cb-2ac3-4152-97c7-b3b8e009d33e" TYPE="swap"
```

Here is the resulting /boot/grub/grub.cfg:

```
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  set have_grubenv=true
  load_env
fi
if [ "${next_entry}" ] ; then
   set default="${next_entry}"
   set next_entry=
   save_env next_entry
   set boot_once=true
else
   set default="0"
fi

if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
  menuentry_id_option="--id"
else
  menuentry_id_option=""
fi

export menuentry_id_option

if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}
function recordfail {
  set recordfail=1
  if [ -n "${have_grubenv}" ]; then if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then save_env recordfail; fi; fi
}
function load_video {
  if [ x$feature_all_video_module = xy ]; then
    insmod all_video
  else
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod ieee1275_fb
    insmod vbe
    insmod vga
    insmod video_bochs
    insmod video_cirrus
  fi
}

if [ x$feature_default_font_path = xy ] ; then
   font=unicode
else
insmod part_msdos
insmod lvm
insmod ext2
set root='lvmid/nFNWNq-E4w8-3z7b-IuV2-2F6T-z0Mu-GqxJHK/5vOz1c-nclp-Qee2-PGjc-oXFP-Skav-K2wend'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint='lvmid/nFNWNq-E4w8-3z7b-IuV2-2F6T-z0Mu-GqxJHK/5vOz1c-nclp-Qee2-PGjc-oXFP-Skav-K2wend'  f55ffea3-bf95-435a-bb3f-d0123f1822d7
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root f55ffea3-bf95-435a-bb3f-d0123f1822d7
fi
    font="/usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2"
fi

if loadfont $font ; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  set locale_dir=$prefix/locale
  set lang=en_US
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_output gfxterm
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ] ; then
  set timeout=5
else
  if [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then
    set timeout_style=hidden
    set timeout=3
  # Fallback hidden-timeout code in case the timeout_style feature is
  # unavailable.
  elif sleep --interruptible 3 ; then
    set timeout=0
  fi
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
if [ ! -d /boot/efi ]; then
if hwmatch /boot/grub/nomodesetsystemlist.txt 3; then
if [ ${match} != 0 ]; then
set nomodeset="nomodeset"
fi
fi
fi
function gfxmode {
    set gfxpayload="${1}"
    if [ "${1}" = "keep" ]; then
        set vt_handoff=vt.handoff=7
    else
        set vt_handoff=
    fi
}
set linux_gfx_mode=keep
export linux_gfx_mode
menuentry 'Ubuntu' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-f55ffea3-bf95-435a-bb3f-d0123f1822d7' {
    recordfail
    load_video
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,msdos1'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1 --hint='hd0,msdos1'  5bd116ab-46ef-4b4e-ac70-711cd0085a55
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 5bd116ab-46ef-4b4e-ac70-711cd0085a55
    fi
    linux   /vmlinuz-4.2.0-35-generic root=/dev/mapper/vg1-root ro   quiet splash pciehp.pciehp_force=1 radeon.modeset=0 nouveau.modeset=0 $vt_handoff $nomodeset
    initrd  /initrd.img-4.2.0-35-generic
}
submenu 'Advanced options for Ubuntu' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-f55ffea3-bf95-435a-bb3f-d0123f1822d7' {
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.2.0-35-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.2.0-35-generic-advanced-f55ffea3-bf95-435a-bb3f-d0123f1822d7' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos1'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1 --hint='hd0,msdos1'  5bd116ab-46ef-4b4e-ac70-711cd0085a55
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 5bd116ab-46ef-4b4e-ac70-711cd0085a55
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 4.2.0-35-generic ...'
        linux   /vmlinuz-4.2.0-35-generic root=/dev/mapper/vg1-root ro   quiet splash pciehp.pciehp_force=1 radeon.modeset=0 nouveau.modeset=0 $vt_handoff $nomodeset
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /initrd.img-4.2.0-35-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.2.0-35-generic (safe mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.2.0-35-generic-recovery-f55ffea3-bf95-435a-bb3f-d0123f1822d7' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos1'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1 --hint='hd0,msdos1'  5bd116ab-46ef-4b4e-ac70-711cd0085a55
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 5bd116ab-46ef-4b4e-ac70-711cd0085a55
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 4.2.0-35-generic ...'
        linux   /vmlinuz-4.2.0-35-generic root=/dev/mapper/vg1-root ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /initrd.img-4.2.0-35-generic
    }
}

### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###
menuentry 'Memory test (memtest86+)' {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,msdos1'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1 --hint='hd0,msdos1'  5bd116ab-46ef-4b4e-ac70-711cd0085a55
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 5bd116ab-46ef-4b4e-ac70-711cd0085a55
    fi
    knetbsd /memtest86+.elf
}
menuentry 'Memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115200)' {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,msdos1'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1 --hint='hd0,msdos1'  5bd116ab-46ef-4b4e-ac70-711cd0085a55
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 5bd116ab-46ef-4b4e-ac70-711cd0085a55
    fi
    linux16 /memtest86+.bin console=ttyS0,115200n8
}
### END /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###
```

I also checked for EFI, but /sys/firmware/efi* is not present (this is an HP zBook15).

I'm running out of ideas and don't really want to nuke the whole system just because I can't get grub properly installed.  Any helpful ideas on what I missed?

### Update 1

Should have included this in my original question.  Here is the output from update-grub:

```
root@Microknoppix:/# update-grub
Generating grub configuration file ...
  /dev/sda2: open failed: No such device or address
  /dev/sda7: open failed: No such device or address
  /dev/sda8: open failed: No such device or address
  /dev/sda2: open failed: No such device or address
  /dev/sda7: open failed: No such device or address
  /dev/sda8: open failed: No such device or address
  /dev/sda2: open failed: No such device or address
  /dev/sda7: open failed: No such device or address
  /dev/sda8: open failed: No such device or address
  /dev/sda2: open failed: No such device or address
  /dev/sda7: open failed: No such device or address
  /dev/sda8: open failed: No such device or address
  /dev/sda2: open failed: No such device or address
  /dev/sda7: open failed: No such device or address
  /dev/sda8: open failed: No such device or address
  /dev/sda2: open failed: No such device or address
  /dev/sda7: open failed: No such device or address
  /dev/sda8: open failed: No such device or address
  /dev/sda2: open failed: No such device or address
  /dev/sda7: open failed: No such device or address
  /dev/sda8: open failed: No such device or address
  /dev/sda2: open failed: No such device or address
  /dev/sda7: open failed: No such device or address
  /dev/sda8: open failed: No such device or address
Warning: Setting GRUB_TIMEOUT to a non-zero value when GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT is set is no longer supported.
  /dev/sda2: open failed: No such device or address
  /dev/sda7: open failed: No such device or address
  /dev/sda8: open failed: No such device or address
  /dev/sda2: open failed: No such device or address
  /dev/sda7: open failed: No such device or address
  /dev/sda8: open failed: No such device or address
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-35-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-35-generic
  /dev/sda2: open failed: No such device or address
  /dev/sda7: open failed: No such device or address
  /dev/sda8: open failed: No such device or address
  /dev/sda2: open failed: No such device or address
  /dev/sda7: open failed: No such device or address
  /dev/sda8: open failed: No such device or address
Found memtest86+ image: /memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /memtest86+.bin
done
```

/dev/sda2, 7 and 8 were all partitions I've deleted.

Here is my fdisk output:

```
root@Microknoppix:/# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 512.1 GB, 512110190592 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 62260 cylinders, total 1000215216 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x64a7963a

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048     4196351     2097152   83  Linux
/dev/sda3         8802304   999215103   495206400    f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda4       999215104  1000214527      499712    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/sda5       911216640   991215615    39999488   83  Linux
/dev/sda6         8804352   911214591   451205120   8e  Linux LVM

Partition table entries are not in disk order

Disk /dev/mapper/vg1-home: 214.7 GB, 214748364800 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 26108 cylinders, total 419430400 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/vg1-home doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/mapper/vg1-root: 42.9 GB, 42949672960 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 5221 cylinders, total 83886080 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/vg1-root doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/mapper/vg1-swap: 42.9 GB, 42949672960 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 5221 cylinders, total 83886080 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/vg1-swap doesn't contain a valid partition table
```

Comment: Do not confuse ESP - efi system partition, a FAT32 UEFI boot partition which is for UEFI boot (including grub boot files), and a /boot Linux partition as ext4 used for Ubuntu's boot files & more of grub. If system was UEFI/gpt you have both the ESP & /boot. If BIOS/MBR you only have /boot, but if on gpt partitioned drive then must add a bios_grub partition for grub to install correctly with BIOS/gpt.

Comment: It seems to be a BIOS/MBR with GPT.  Not sure what the bios_grub partition is... the final partition configuration is shown above.  /dev/sda1 is /boot, /dev/sda3 is the extended partition, /dev/sda4 is HP Tools, /dev/sda5 is an old linux partition and /dev/sda6 is the Physical Volume for LVM.

Comment: If you have an extended partition with logical partitions it is MBR, not gpt. In effect all partitions with gpt are primary. And a few BIOS do expect the boot flag even though grub does not use it.

Comment: @oldfred Thanks for the explanation.  It seems the BIOS did expect the boot flag (see my answer below).  I'd upvote your comment, but I'm not yet allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I added the boot flag (yes, that obsolete flag) to the first partition and that seems to have fixed it.  We suspect that the BIOS was looking for that somewhere in the partition table before checking the MBR for a boot loader.

*sigh* Some things just never die....

Answer (score 0):

Things to check:

- Switch boot options from UEFI to Normal
- Check boot devices list & order
- Make sure the GRUB menu is not just hidden (you can hold an arrow key during boot)

Comment: I should have stated the boot error.  "No operating system found", so I'm pretty sure that is from the BIOS and it is never finding Grub.